# как связать Angular 2+ с базами данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql-server, angular2, angular4

Как angular 2+ взаимодействовать(запись, чтение, обнова) с базой данных (например MySQL)?
Как развернуть базу на внутреннем сервере приложения? (тот что ng server)
Как увидеть интерфейс MySQL на внутреннем сервере приложения?

Comment: Angular это UI фреймворк и никакого отношения с БД он не имеет. Связать Angular напрямую с sql-server невозможно. Вам нужно реализовывать промежуточный слой (какой-то бекенд).

Comment: какая логика работы промежуточного слоя, и на чем его проще реализовать?

Comment: @Kurinnoy, этот вопрос не имеет конкретного ответа. Всё зависит от заданий вашего приложения. Т.е. начиная от простого получения данных с БД и отправки их на UI в удобном виде до реализации нейронных сетей =)))